# How would I produce unevenly colored subtitles with aegisub

Tags: subtitles

I would like to put text on screen that would have non-even colour. I.e. if the text were "subtitle", "s" would be in say white and "e" in gray. Is there a way to accomplish this using Aegisub/ASS subtitle format? So far, it let me do anything I needed with graphical subtitles, but I cannot figure how to do this one.

(On a related note - what is the best way to ask ASS-related questions since the aegisub forum is down?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use the Hydra Aegisub plugin from here: https://unanimated.github.io/ts/scripts-manuals.htm#hydra

And it all works.